# Custom Post types as category in another custom post type in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a WordPress website that contains 3 custom post types.

1. teacher
2. class
3. video

My requirement is

(1) when adding video I need to select the teacher's name and save it. (i.e. teacher as category in video post type)

(2) when adding classes I need to select both teacher's name and video and save it.

How do I do that?

Comment: You hire a developer to do it for you. :)

Comment: You have to considerate using SchoolPress:
https://github.com/bwawwp/schoolpress

Comment: Don't use custom post types, make use of custom taxonomies

Comment: Take a look at WordPress meta boxes http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box. You can add a new metabox as a select field with a query for each of the above and save to the custom post type. If you want the teachers as a category, it'd be easiest to just create a custom taxonomy as @PieterGoosen suggested.